# Movie taking place in a fair, including a giant woman in a dress stepping over the eating area

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

Old movie I watched as a kid around the early 2000’s. Movie looked older. I only remember a scene as follows: there’s a dad and son eating and a giantess wearing a dress/skirt literally walks past overhead. The dad says something to the son along the lines of “becoming a man” that day.
Scene takes place during the night. Bright signs from the rides in the background.

Characters were Caucasian. English language. Movie was shot in color.

I only remember that scene and it has been bugging me for years trying to figure out which movie it was. Don’t believe it was an R rated film since I watched it with family.

Comment: Just to check: was the giant woman an actual giant (like fantasy giants) or she was just quite tall for a human? The former is on-topic, but the later wouldn't, I'm afraid.

Comment: I believe she was an actual giant. From what I recall, she steps over the eating area of a fairground. The scene was taking place during the nighttime with bright signs in the background

Comment: Alright, I think it's on-topic then. Could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in?

Comment: @Jenayah , just read them. I’ve added information. Thank you

Comment: @Paulie_D , sorry. I don’t recall the size difference.

Answer (score 6):

This is from "[**Dude, Where's My Car**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0242423/)" (2000)...the scene in question is...

For a longer version (lower quality I'm afraid).